# Defining a representation on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: sage, representation, gap-system

I want to define a representation on $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, or generally, over any free group with two generators on GAP.

I am using

```
repsn
```

package for this. I have written the code

```
LoadPackage("repsn");;
f := FreeGroup("x","y");;
G := f / [f.1^2, f.2^3];;
rho := IrreducibleAffordingRepresentation(Irr(G));
```

But getting error on GAP (SAGE online interface): https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzzyU9MCUhMzk5MT9VQKkotKM5T0rS25uVKU7CyVXArSk11L8ovLdBQqlDSUaqESLmDpNIU9BWi0_QM44x0FNL0jOKMQZShFpCpBRLVBTNjgaqLMvJB6j2LilJTSpMzk3JSHdPS8otSMvPSg1ILilKLU_NKEksy8_M0gEo03DWjjWM1rQF-MSwg&lang=gap&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==

Could someone please tell me a fix?

Comment: I am afraid that's a question to be asked directly to SageMath developers (see [here](https://www.sagemath.org/help.html)). The error complains about GAP producing wrong output, but it works in GAP. You can also try to locate more precisely at which step the error occurs, by doing calculation step by step. For me, `Irr(G);` as a separate line works, but trying `irr:=Irr(G);` to save the output for future use triggers the same error. Alternatively, "just use GAP", unless you have a strong reason to use it within SageMath ;-)